# psql: error: could not connect to server: FATAL: password authentication failed for user while connecting to dockerized postgres image

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I tried to access my Postgres DB that running in docker, here is my docker-compose.yml:

```
Version: "3.8"
   
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=fdc_dashboard
      - POSTGRES_USER=admin
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=saya1234
```

It successfully run using:

> docker-compose up db

but when I tried to connect to it

```
psql -h localhost -p 5432 -d fdc_dashboard -U admin  --password
```

It raised:

```
psql: error: could not connect to server: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "admin"
```

Is there something that I missed?

Comment: Which environment you're using?

Comment: @Ashok sorry sir, what do you mean by environment?

Comment: Windows or Linux

Comment: @Ashok Im using mac